# Want to run a Python "print()" script from Java, but getting no output

Tags: python, java

I have a simple Python script:

```
def main():
    print("Hello world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I want to get the response in Java. The endpoint is:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class TestPython {

    @PostMapping("/endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<String> endpoint() throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("path-to-venv", "path-to-python-script");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        String jsonResponse = sb.toString();

        BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        StringBuilder errorSb = new StringBuilder();
        String errorLine;
        while ((errorLine = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
            errorSb.append(errorLine);
        }
        String errorOutput = errorSb.toString();

        if (!errorOutput.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Error output: " + errorOutput);
        }

        System.out.println(jsonResponse);
        System.out.println(errorOutput);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(jsonResponse);
    }
}
```

jsonResponse and errorOutput are both empty. My virtual environment is active and I am using it. When I execute the Python script via terminal, a cmd pops up and prints `Hello World`, but using Java is empty. I also tried to explicitly set the charset in java, but I get the same problem. Also I get a lot of these `\u0000` characters when executing `reader.cb` in debug mode.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: What does Java's `ProcessBuilder()` do? Is it equivalent to any of: `python script.py`, `python -m script`, `./script.py`, or `python -c "import script; script.main()"` from shell? These are all slightly different ways to "execute" a script.

Comment: ProcessBuilder starts a new process that executes the python script. I am using the virtual environment, not system python interpreter. I am not sure to what shell command is equivalent

Comment: Try executing the script from shell in those various ways, confirming the behavior you want, thereby solving the Python aspect of your problem. What remains is making Java do what you want.

Comment: So this ProcessBuilder is equivalent to first activating the virtual env, then executing the python script, which I am doing the same from the terminal and it works. I am confused

Comment: What is `"path-to-venv"` a path to? A venv is a folder, not an executable.

Comment: I'd search for "how to execute script and capture stdout from script in Java", as it seems the Python part seems solved. Looks like you'd get the same problem with a bash script that just `echo "hey"`.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100%, but you can try to flush the output stream of your Python script. It's possible that the output is not being sent until the script completes, so flushing the stream may help. You can try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` at the end of your Python script to force the output to be flushed.

edit (I few other things to try):

- Make sure that the Python script has execute permissions. If the Python script is not marked as executable, you may need to set the execute permission using the chmod command in your terminal.
- Triple check the path's you're using in the ProcessBuilder, that object also has a few other constructors you could try that may work better.
- You can also try using a different method for executing the Python script, such as `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`

Comment: Still the same problem :/